# htaccess redirect puts old path in parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to forward one specific URL to another one. Tried this:

```
Redirect 301 "/stellenangebote-berlin" "http://mydomain.de/stellenangebote-in/berlin"
```

The forward works, but the old URL is appended as parameter like so:

```
www.newURL/deeplink.php?path=stellenangebote-berlin
```

This breaks my further routing. How can I prevent the script from adding the old path? 
Thanks!

Comment: The Redirect directive itself would not do that. It is supposed to automatically append a shared path suffix, but not make up a query string on its own. You must have other stuff around this that influences this.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! So can I add some if-then-else thing in the htaccess so I get only the specific url redirected but all the rest handled by the rewrites? Thanks again1

Comment: Use a RewriteRule instead of Redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like below because I'm using the below way in my server and it's working fine.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.de/stellenangebote-in/berlin [R=301,L]
```

Or you can try it in one more way like below.This one redirects everything after the domain name on the url to the exact same copy on the new domain url:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.de/stellenangebote-in/berlin$1 [R=301,L]
```